# Links don't work or display correctly in PHP

Tags: php, css

I made a header design in html file and everything worked nice, but when I put it in .php file they became like idle so I can't click or hover them. PHP code:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once "stuff.php";
if (isset($_SESSION['encnick'])){
    header("Location: my.php");
    return;
}
//On form submit
if (isset($_POST['register'])){
    if (!isset($_POST['nick'])){
        $_SESSION['error'] = "Nickname is required";
        header("Location: register.php");
        return;
    }
    if (!isset($_POST['password'])){
        $_SESSION['error'] = "Password is required";
        header("Location: register.php");
        return;
    }
    if (!isset($_POST['cpassword'])){
        $_SESSION['error'] = "Password is required";
        header("Location: register.php");
        return;
    }
    if ($_POST['password'] !== $_POST['cpassword']){
        $_SESSION['error'] = "Passwords don't match";
        header("Location: register.php");
        return;
    }
    else{
        $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE nick = :nick");
        $statement->execute(array(':nick' => $_POST['nick']));
        $row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if ($row['nick'] === $_POST['nick']){
            $_SESSION['error'] = "This nickname is already taken";
            header("Location: register.php");
            return;
        }
        $statement = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO users (nick, password, company, encodednick, user_group) VALUES (:nick, :password, :company, :encodednick, :user_group)");
        $statement->execute(array(
                ':nick' => htmlentities($_POST['nick']),
            ':password' => password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT),
            ':company' => htmlentities($_POST['company']),
            ':encodednick' => md5($_POST['nick']),
            ':user_group' => "user"
            ));
        $_SESSION['encnick'] = md5($_POST['nick']);
        $encnick = $_SESSION['encnick'];
        header("Location: my.php?id=$encnick");
        return;
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>ReactSynchro</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/register.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fonts.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
<?php printheader() ?>
<div id="formdiv">
    <form method="post">
        <label for="nick">Nickname</label>
        <input type="text" name="nick" id="nick" placeholder="Enter unique nickname" minlength="6" maxlength="30" required>
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter password" minlength="8" maxlength="60" required>
        <label for="cpassword">Confirm Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="cpassword" id="cpassword" placeholder="Confirm password" minlength="8" maxlength="50" required>
        <label for="company">Company</label>
        <input type="text" name="company" id="company" placeholder="Enter your company" minlength="3" maxlength="50">
        <input type="submit" value="Register" name="register" id="regbtn">
    </form>
</div>
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['error'])){
    echo "<h2 id='errormessage'>".$_SESSION['error']."</h2>";
    unset($_SESSION['error']);
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

main.css code:

```
body{
    background-color: #333;
    margin: 0;
}
#header{
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #444;
    height: 110px;
}
#header img{
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    left: 5px;
    top: 5px;
    bottom: 5px;
}
#header a{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 0.5px solid white;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu';
    font-size: 20px;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 200ms linear;
    -ms-transition: background-color 200ms linear;
    transition: background-color 200ms linear;
    -moz-transition: background-color 200ms linear;
    -o-transition: background-color 200ms linear;
}
#hlinks1{
    position: relative;
    left: 120px;
    top: -71px;
}
#hlinks2{
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
#hlinks2 a{
    background-color: rgba(255, 140, 0, 0.9);
}
#hlinks1 a:hover{
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
#hlinks2 a:hover{
    background-color: rgba(255, 140, 0, 1);
}
#errormessage{
    color: red;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu';
}
@media all and (max-width: 537px){
    #hsupbtn{
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}
@media all and (max-width: 440px){
    #hregbtn{
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}
```

register.css code:

```
#formdiv{
    width: 50%;
    height: 350px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    border: 0.5px solid white;
    max-width: 500px;
    min-width: 250px;
}
#formdiv label{
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu';
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 50px;
}
#formdiv input{
    width: 90%;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu';
    line-height: 20px;
}
#regbtn{
    width: 50% !important;
    top: 20px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 140, 0, 0.9);
    color: white;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 200ms linear;
    -ms-transition: background-color 200ms linear;
    transition: background-color 200ms linear;
    -moz-transition: background-color 200ms linear;
    -o-transition: background-color 200ms linear;
}
#regbtn:hover{
    background-color: rgba(255, 140, 0, 1);
}
#formdiv input:empty{
    border: 0.5px solid white;
}
#formdiv input:valid{
    border: 0.5px solid green;
}
```

The menu printing function in stuff.php file:

```
function printheader(){
    echo "<div id='header'>
    <img src='images/logo.png'>
    <div id='hlinks1'>
        <a href='../index.php'>Home</a>
        <a href='../about.html'>About</a>
        <a href='../support.php' id='hsupbtn'>Support</a>
    </div>
    <div id='hlinks2'>
        <a href='../register.php' id='hregbtn'>Register</a>
        <a href='../login.php'>Login</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div style='height: 110px; position: relative;'></div>";
}
```

So I mean that when I hover or click links nothing happens at all, they are idle like pictures, but if I disconnect main.css file they start working normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have following in your **printheader function**

```
<div style='height: 110px; position: relative;'></div>
```

Remove the following:-

```
position: relative
```